# A non-convergent sequence in R for which every convergent subsequences converges to 1

Tags: linear-algebra

I was told such a sequence could exist but didn't believe it. Is an example of the title statement possible?

Answer (score 2):

If a trivial example such as $1,2,3,...$ does not satisfy you because it has no convergent sequences, then consider $1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,...$ and note that any sequence of integers converges if and only if it is eventually constant(that is, there is some large $N$ such that the sequence $a_{n+N}$ is constant).

Therefore any convergent sequence must converge to $1$, since every other integer only comes once(or never) in the sequence.

But the big sequence itself doesn't converge for the same reason as above : let alone being constant, no two consecutive integers are even the same in the sequence. Hence, we see that the sequence itself does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $1,2,3,\dots$ is one such sequence.

---

Or, if you want a sequence which actually has a convergent subsequence, take

$$1,\frac{3}{2}, 2,\frac43,3,\frac54,4,\frac65,\dots$$

Comment: How is the first one an example? That sequence converges to $\;\infty\;$ and thus also *any* convergence converges to $\;\infty\;$ ...Unless "convergence" means (for you, for the OP...) convergence to a *finite* limit. Then I suppose that sequence $\;1,2,3\;$ fulfills the conditions in an empty way.

Comment: @DonAntonio The sequence has no convergent subsequences, and therefore, all convergent subsequences converge to  $1$. And also, all convergent subsequences converge to $1$. And also, all convergent subsequences are invisible pink elephants. (note: a sequence that converges to $\infty$ is **not** a convergent sequence).

Comment: Also note that the sequence cannot be bounded, or otherwise there will either be convergent subsequences that converge to something else, or else the whole sequence would converge to $1$... Thus, it will have subsequences "converging" to either $-\infty$ or $\infty$ (or both) and the claim would be false if we by any chance decided to call those subsequences "convergent".